# Determining position of different elements

Tags: html, image, css

I have got an image file to code a web-page. It consists of lot of sections.

Please Note: I am not referring to PSD to html conversion. It's need to be done manually.

My question is : How can we determine positional values, dimensions for a particular element such as an image, text? Is there any extension or tool for viewing the properties from an image file in offline mode. How can it be done?

If the question is duplicate, please provide the links or tutorial to follow the procedure.

Comment: You can use photoshop to determine image height width, text font family color font size etc.

Comment: What about other dimension values such as margins,paddings and positions?

Comment: you can check that also using photosho e.g gap between 2 elements and position